# Integrating Spring Batch Admin In Spring Boot Web App With Another JPA Persistence

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I have an EAR file which has 1 URL for our main app (Normal UI and JEE Persistence) and Spring Batch Admin 1.3.0. We are updating the technologies to Spring Boot, Spring 5, Spring Data/JPA, Spring Batch 4 and a war file deployment. So far so good, now we are at the point of integrating Spring Batch Admin and I am a bit confused about the best approach. There are many questions and approaches and I am trying to pick between.

As far as Spring Batch Admin, we have made some customization's for our business domain so would prefer to stay with the freemarker approach instead of switching to Angular. So I am starting with the code [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin.git). First step was to update the code for Spring 5/ Batch 4 and then add our customization's back in,

Finally I am at the point to trying to add the Spring Batch Admin UI into the war file. I added the modified Spring Batch Admin jar files into the pom.xml for the war file. The majority of the spring configuration has been migrated to java config. However, all jobs are still in XML files. I placed the data-source-context.xml (loading from JNDI) in the META-INF override directories (as Spring Batch Admin expects. I am seeing a conflict with the "dataSource", and "transactionManager" loaded by SBA and the dataSource and transactionManger I defined in my app (for Spring Data / JPA).

What is the best way to handle the situation? Ideally, SBA admin would just use the spring components already defined. Remove the @EnableBatchAdmin and handle the SBA resource importing in my config classes?

UPDATE:
I followed the approach of discussed [here](https://github.com/abelaneiros/spring-batch-admin-spring-boot) and I see the system start up and UI showup. Now I am trying to load the job xml files. I have generated a java config for the generation of the spring batch admin entities.

Now when I load the job xml files, I see error that it cannot find beans defined in the java config. I thought java and xml configs could co exist in the same project and reference each other spring bean.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch Admin is not maintained anymore. Since you are migrating to Spring Boot, Spring Framework 5 and Spring Batch 4, I recommend that you take the opportunity to modularize your jobs as Spring Boot apps (which is possible with either XML or Java config) and deploy/run them in [Spring Cloud DataFlow](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/).

You can find a migration guide from Spring Batch Admin to Spring Cloud DataFlow here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin/blob/master/MIGRATION.md

Comment: I looked at the migration to Cloud Dataflow and determined that it may be good for microservices and cloud deployments, it wasn't a good fit for our application. The additional complexity for our smaller clients in an environment of a couple servers was a huge drawback. It is much easier to setup a small cluster of app servers. In addition, we have around 100 batch jobs (and about 1/2 partitioned), and the generation of a Spring boot application for each job isn't a good choice for us.